# Java and SSL certificates

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to establish a connection with a PHP script of mine in Java using the secure socket layer (HTTPS), but I have found out that to ensure maximum security/validity I have to import the SSL certificate that my website uses into my application... Something I don't know how to do.

If it helps, my SSL Certificate is not self signed, rather provided by [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com) AND I am using Eclipse IDE.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? i.e. What files do I need, where should I import them and what code do I need in Java, etc?

Comment: If it works without importing any certificate, I don't see how the security would be ensured/increased by importing the web site certificate. If any certificate must be imported it's StartSSL's root certificate, but not your website certificate, because Java could not recognize StartSSL as a valid certification authority.

Comment: @JB Oh. It was just because in my previous question chubbard said that I should be sure to validate the server's certificate in my client to make sure that I am talking to a false service and he mentioned something about keytool. So if your saying that importing the website certificate doesn't affect security, why would anyone import an SSL certificate?

Comment: It's Java's SSL stack that will validate the web site certificate, just as a browser does. Do you import the certificate of all the SSL websites you visit before visiting them? No. The browser validates their certificate because it's certified by a well-known certificate authority that the browser knows. StartSSL is the certificate authority in your case. Java does the same thing. You might need to import StartSSL's certificate, but not the website certificate.

Comment: Also, my SSL certificate is actually verified/provide by StartCom Ltd. though StartSLL so if there are were to get StartCom's root certificate (somehow), would Java recognize that as a valid certification authority and therefore know whether it is talking to a false service or not when connecting to my PHP Script?

Comment: Read Vineet's answer. It's perfect.

Comment: Yes, Vineet's answer did help a lot, but thanks for your input as well!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I have found out that to ensure maxium security/validity I have to import the SSL certificate that my website uses into my application

You are partially right when you make that statement. You do not need to import your SSL certificate. It is sufficient that the StartSSL CA certificate be imported.

Additionally, there is no such thing as importing a certificate into a Java application. SSL support in Java relies on the concept of keystores and truststores, and not on some certificate packaged within your application. If you are publishing your application to be downloaded and executed by end-users, there is no need for your to publish your certificate or for that matter your private key in your application. The private key, and the associated certificate would be stored in a keystore, that only you may access.

The end-users of your application would rely on the SSL support within the Java runtime, that would enable the application to establish SSL connections to sites, after the server-certificate is verified. The Java runtime ships with a default set of CA certificates in a truststore, and the only prerequisite for SSL connections to be successfully established is that the SSL certificate of the server be issued by one of the CAs in the truststore. ***The certificates of StartSSL are not present in the truststore of the Java runtime***, atleast as of version 6, and therefore:

- You could instruct your end users to perform the activity of importing the StartSSL CA certificate into the Java truststore. Links that may help include [this StartSSL forum thread](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1678) (only the first 4 steps are needed to import the CA certs into a truststore), [a GitHub project](https://github.com/haron/startssl-java), and [this blog post](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/52-Java-and-the-StartSSL-CA-certificates.html); a disclaimer - I haven't attempted using any of those and you ought to be using it at your own risk.
- Or, you could initialize your application with your own truststore using the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path_to_truststore> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<truststore_password>` JVM startup flags, or execute the following code before initializing SSL connections:

  ```
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","<path_to_truststore>");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","<truststore_password>");
  ```

  This is a viable approach only if your application is a Java SE application that does not happen to be an applet (or an application with similar restrictions on how the truststore is specified).

---

It would also help to read up the [Java keytool documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

Comment: Thank you for your informative and 'insightful' answer! Basically what you're saying then, is that I should just need to import StartSSL's CA certificate and then I should be secure to go? If I am correct, the links you provided only apply to the end user and the certificate would not be distributed with my software, but the method(s) in your second bullet point mean that StartSSL's CA certificate will always be there and my end users will not have to do anything? Because I don't really want my customers to have to be importing StartSSL's CA certificate...

Comment: The CA certificate serves multiple purposes; for a Java server like Tomcat that may serve a site over HTTPS with the site certificate issued by StartSSL, you will need to have a keystore with the site certificate, and also a *truststore with the StartSSL CA certificate*. A SSL client, like a browser, or your Java application, needs to only have the StartSSL CA certificate in the truststore (or whatever is used to verify trust). Your end users would therefore have to import the CA cert into the cacerts file, and the connection made by the app would be secure.

Comment: ... I don't know if it makes a difference but I do plan on using launch4j to distribute the JRE with my applications so that I don't have to rely on my customers have Java installed. So, could that mean that StartSSL's CA Certificate gets packaged in with the JRE as well?

Comment: The methods in the second bullet point, indicate that you can ship your own trusstore, and get Java to use that, instead of relying on the default Java truststore - typically the `cacerts` file in jre/libe/security of a JRE installation.

Comment: With launch4j, things become a bit tricky. If you are embedding a JRE within the executable, you'll need to modify it's `cacerts` file. A better option would be to investigate the use of [JVM options](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Additional_jvm_options) and specify the location of the truststore; this might require you to place the truststore outside the executable though. Edit: I noticed that you are bundling the JRE, so you may ignore the point regarding additional JVM options.

Comment: So basically Vineet, if I import the CA certificate into my cacerts file, as that is in my JRE directory and I do bundle the JRE with my Java application, surely my customers would not have to do anything because I have already done it for them?

Comment: Oh, that's great. I will see to importing the CA certificate as soon as possible now. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: I don't know if any one will answer this now, but could someone just verify where the JAVA_HOME environmental needs to point to please.

Comment: It need not point to any location when you're using launch4j (unless your code relies on that env variable). But if you are attempting to locate the `keytool` executable, it is available in both the JRE and the JDK, in the `JAVA_HOM/bin` directory. So, if you've installed Java in `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`, that would be `JAVA_HOME`, with keytool being in the `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: The reason for me asking is not because of either of then reasons. The GitHub project requires the JAVA_HOME environmental variable to be set up correctly - but, yes, I thought it was the JDK installation path, not the JRE one! So I have now installed StartSSL's CA Certificate, how do I know that it has gone on correctly and Java has recognized it?

Comment: It's sufficient if you follow the StartSSL forum thread. All you need to ensure is that you have the StartSSL Root CA and Intermediate CA certs to import into the truststore. The github project does nothing except for providing a Windows batch script to import the certs (that come with the project, but really, you can download these certs). On the topic of testing the truststore correctness, you could do so with a Java program that makes a HTTPS connection to a site using a StartSSL cert.

Answer (score 3):

The following method loads the default (cacerts) keystore, checks to see if a certificate is installed, and installs it if not. It eliminates the need to manually run the `keystore` command on any servers.

It assumes that the default keystore password (changeit) is unchanged, update `CACERTS_PASSWORD` if not. Note that the method saves the keystore after adding a certificate, so after being run once the certificate will permanently be in the store.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

/**
 * Add a certificate to the cacerts keystore if it's not already included
 */
public class SslUtil {
    private static final String CACERTS_PATH = "/lib/security/cacerts";

    // NOTE: DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT CODE, LOAD AT RUNTIME FROM A SECURE CONFIG
    // DEFAULT CACERTS PASSWORD IS PROVIDED HERE AS A QUICK, NOT-FOR-PRODUCTION WORKING EXAMPLE
    // ALSO, CHANGE THE DEFAULT CACERTS PASSWORD, AS IT IMPLORES YOU TO!
    private static final String CACERTS_PASSWORD = "changeit";

    /**
     * Add a certificate to the cacerts keystore if it's not already included
     * 
     * @param alias The alias for the certificate, if added
     * @param certInputStream The certificate input stream
     * @throws KeyStoreException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws CertificateException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void ensureSslCertIsInKeystore(String alias, InputStream certInputStream)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException{
        //get default cacerts file
        final File cacertsFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + CACERTS_PATH);
        if (!cacertsFile.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(cacertsFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        //load cacerts keystore
        FileInputStream cacertsIs = new FileInputStream(cacertsFile);
        final KeyStore cacerts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        cacerts.load(cacertsIs, CACERTS_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        cacertsIs.close();

        //load certificate from input stream
        final CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        final Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
        certInputStream.close();

        //check if cacerts contains the certificate
        if (cacerts.getCertificateAlias(cert) == null) {
            //cacerts doesn't contain the certificate, add it
            cacerts.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
            //write the updated cacerts keystore
            FileOutputStream cacertsOs = new FileOutputStream(cacertsFile);
            cacerts.store(cacertsOs, CACERTS_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            cacertsOs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
SslUtil.ensureSslCertIsInKeystore("startssl", new FileInputStream("/path/to/cert.crt"));
```

Comment: in my code this results in an java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security\cacerts (Access is denied)    i download the certs to a temp folder, then import it with an unique alias (not starttls) and the fileInputStream. my certificate come from an HTTPS server (www.gmx.at)

Comment: Question, isn't it a pretty big security hole to store a password as plain-text in your code? Or does that not matter when it comes to SSL connections?

Comment: @Flaom yes, absolutely storing plain text passwords in code is a bad idea. The password above (`changeit`) is the default cacerts password which is meant to be changed. I'll add a note to the code snippet pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the mailgun engineers for some reason don't want to give us clear instructions on how to solve this.  This is what I did

We run tomcat8 and connect via jersey web services to the mailgun API.  I followed this users instructions and it worked fine.  Hope this helps someone.

On 1/22, we updated our SSL certificates due to Symantec's PKI infrastructure set to become untrusted. Some older versions of Java do not have the "DigiCert Global Root G2" CA.

There are several options:

Import the "DigiCert Global Root G2" CA into your "cacerts" file.
Upgrade your JRE to 8u91 (or higher), which includes this root.
To import the "DigiCert Global Root G2" You can download the root from https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm. Ensure you are downloading the correct root certificate.

Once the certificate is downloaded, you'll need to import it into with a command like the following:

keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /path/to/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias digicert-global-root-g2 -file /path/to/digicert.crt
You will need to set the path to your Java Keystore and the location of the root certificate you downloaded.

---

So 
1. /path/to/digicert.crt is the file you just downloaded.
2. /path/to/cacerts - This is in your JRE path.  I "find / -name cacerts -print"  this will help you quickly find all the java cacerts on your filesystem.  For me it was /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article: http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php
It contains code example which may help in case if you are trying to access your script from code.

Note that you either should use system properties

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
```

to pass the SSL certificate to JVM or import it into JRE keystore by using [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) tool

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sergey. Unfortunately, I had already looked at the article you suggested. It probably would be helpful if I studied it a bit longer but this is a completely new subject for me and I'm under a bit of time pressure so, I hate to say it but I was looking for the easiest way out here. Fortunately, I have discovered the best way for me in discussion with Vineet, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> I have found out that to ensure maxium security/validity I have to
>   import the SSL certificate

No you don't. You only need that step if your clients don't already trust the signer of the server certificate, which only arises if the server certificate is self-signed or signed e.g. by an internal CA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, unfortunately I have already imported a certificate - but I don't that that it was necessary at all now, but how would I know if my clients don't trust the signer of the server certificate: would I receive an exception from my application when using `Htttpsurlconnection`?

Comment: @Andy you would get the same exception you got in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

That article contains the code for changing trust store's password and adding other certificates there:

[thetechawesomeness.ideasmatter.info](http://thetechawesomeness.ideasmatter.info/changing-trust-store-password.html)