# gradlew unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, gradlew

I am modding with Minecraft Forge. For those who do not know what Forge is, it is a program that keeps mods from destroying the Minecraft source code and helps mods coexist. It also contains a development kit so Java programmers can make their own mods (I am assuming that you know what Minecraft is). I recently aquired a new version of Forge and am attempting to create a new workspace. However, whenever I run the following command in Windows command prompt:

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

I get the following output:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1969)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1846)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1655)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:260)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1086)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processRecord(Handshaker.java:1020)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1137)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1563)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:236)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:226)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1825)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 29 more
```

I tried running this command to fix the problem:

```
gradlew clean
```

but I got the exact same error!

My JAVA_HOME variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.

EDIT: I followed your suggestion and changed the https to http in the gradle properties file, and it actually started working. However, I am now getting *this* error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod 
(file:/C:/Users/James/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14-
bin/ahcidmhfbcpw2l6c6ohng55pk/gradle-2.14/lib/gradle-base-services-2.14.jar) 
to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal 
reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please 
consider using the daemon: 
https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'forge'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.1.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.1/asm-debug-all-5.1.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.1/asm-debug-all-5.1.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:18.0.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:18.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.cloudbees:diff4j:1.1.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.cloudbees:diff4j:1.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/cloudbees/diff4j/1.1/diff4j-1.1.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/cloudbees/diff4j/1.1/diff4j-1.1.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.github.abrarsyed.jastyle:jAstyle:1.3.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.github.abrarsyed.jastyle:jAstyle:1.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/abrarsyed/jastyle/jAstyle/1.3/jAstyle-1.3.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/abrarsyed/jastyle/jAstyle/1.3/jAstyle-1.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:2.1.0.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:2.1.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/2.1.0/trove4j-2.1.0.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/2.1.0/trove4j-2.1.0.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.github.jponge:lzma-java:1.3.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.github.jponge:lzma-java:1.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jponge/lzma-java/1.3/lzma-java-1.3.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jponge/lzma-java/1.3/lzma-java-1.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.nothome:javaxdelta:2.0.1.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.nothome:javaxdelta:2.0.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/nothome/javaxdelta/2.0.1/javaxdelta-2.0.1.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/nothome/javaxdelta/2.0.1/javaxdelta-2.0.1.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.github.tony19:named-regexp:0.2.3.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve com.github.tony19:named-regexp:0.2.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/tony19/named-regexp/0.2.3/named-regexp-0.2.3.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/tony19/named-regexp/0.2.3/named-regexp-0.2.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3.
 Required by:
     :forge:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT
  > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.3/httpmime-4.3.3.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.3/httpmime-4.3.3.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 48.897 secs
```

It looks like the "could not find valid certification path to requested target" error again. I have tried using many different versions of the command including:

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --refresh-dependencies

gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse

gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse --refresh-depencencies
```

These all resulted in the same build failure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you need to register the SSL cert with your trust store.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219989/java-and-ssl-certificates

Comment: Is there one main SSL certificate assigned to my computer that I always use, or do I have to choose a certificate from a website like GoDaddy or Verisign? If I have to choose one, what certificates are recommended for this kind of project? Also, how do I register said certificate, and can I do it via command prompt?

Comment: Here is your answer --> http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/29280-solved-issues-setting-up-forge-18/

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially be caused by using an outdated version of Java that does not have the latest SSL certificates.  See [this thread](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/67445-1122-gradlew-setupdecompworkspace-cannot-complete/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to over come a similar problem when creating a Gradle project in Eclipse by checking "[v] Override Workspace settings" then clicking (*) Specific Gradle Version 4.3.1, manually setting "Gradle User Home" to where my version of gradle 4.3.1 is stored on the hard drive & clicking "[v] Offline Mode"